# Force close on Galaxy tab2

Tags: forceclose

I use fallow codes, and we have no problem on SDk, or BlueStacks,
but, when run on  Samsung GalaxyTab2, this makes force close on line 4.
Please help me.

```java
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Myfolder");
File[] list = dir.listFiles();
int total = list.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Yes. I didn't made directory (/Myfolder) on sdcard.
I soved problem by this codes:

```js
if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
File[] list = dir.listFiles();
```